# Papertrail: records with nil whodunnit values and object_changes in logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, paper-trail-gem, ruby-2.6

I've set papertrail to only record changes containing a whodunnit value/when an admin makes a change by using the below condition in my model:

```
has_paper_trail if: proc { |model| PaperTrail.request.whodunnit.present? }
```

However I've noticed there are still a decent amount of records being stored with empty whodunnit values. From having a look at the records, these seem to be mostly 'update' actions all having empty object changes for some reason. I am unsure as to why the value is empty, or how it would get saved at all considering the above condition.

I am getting whodunnit values from warden in my application controller using:

```
def user_for_paper_trail
  request.env['warden']&.user(:admin)&.id
end
```

Has anyone come across similar behaviour before?

Comment: What kind of object are you storing in `whodunnit`?

Comment: Also, can you confirm that you aren't also using an `unless` option on the same model?

Comment: Also I'd like you know if you're using `info_for_paper_trail` in any of your controllers, or manually setting the value  `PaperTrail.request.controller_info`. If you are including a `whodunnit` key in either of those it could potentially be overriding the value.

Comment: @taylorthurlow I'm storing string ids in whodunnit, and I have a separate `whodunnit_type` column which stores string model names to differentiate between user types. I'm using `info_for_paper_trail` to populate this column via `{ whodunnit_type:  request.env['warden']&.user(:admin).class&.name }`). Both of these columns and changesets seem to be blank in about 50% of my collected logs.

Comment: Hmm, OK. I don't have any other theories, sorry.

Comment: Could this [closed issue](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail/issues/1181) never have been fixed?

Comment: Could it be, by any chance, that the updates with an empty `whodunnit` value have been performed by something other than a controller, e.g. in a background job or via the console? There you'd have to set the `whodunnit` value manually (see here: https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail/wiki/Setting-whodunnit-in-the-rails-console).

Comment: @ClemensKofler don't think so considering there are a few model records saved among the list of invalid records that can only be updated via a controller.

Comment: Are you 100% sure `save_with_version` is not used somewhere in your codebase? https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail/blob/646d7e2c5269ca0a487c8abbc1787db1875bd490/lib/paper_trail/record_trail.rb#L203

Comment: It sounds like you have records being updated in a background job or manually in console, outside of a controller request.  You can update `Papertrail.whodunnit` to save where the command is coming from if you're really stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a `source_location` and `command` field to your papertrail versions table will help you:

1. track *what* command is causing the `nil` whodunnit changes.
2. Ensure you record correctly changes initiated by a **rake task** or **rails console**.

To do this, create a migration to add the `source_location` and `command` fields to your Versions table:

```rb
class AddSourceLocationAndCommandToVersions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :versions, :source_location, :text
    add_column :versions, :command, :text
  end
end
```

I have the following set up in my `papertrail.rb`.  I am using the `JSON serializer` but these changes may work with the normal serializer.  The code after the `serializer` declaration is what is of interest to you:

```rb
require "paper_trail/frameworks/rails"
require "paper_trail"

# the following line is required for PaperTrail >= 4.0.0 with Rails
PaperTrail::Rails::Engine.eager_load!

PaperTrail.config.enabled = true
PaperTrail.serializer = PaperTrail::Serializers::JSON

# Store some metadata about where the change came from, even for rake tasks, etc.
# See: https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail/wiki/Setting-whodunnit-in-the-rails-console
def PaperTrail.set_global_metadata
  request.controller_info ||= {}
  request.controller_info[:command] ||= "#{File.basename($PROGRAM_NAME)} #{ARGV.join ' '} (#{$PID})"
  request.controller_info[:source_location] = caller.find { |line|
    line.starts_with? Rails.root.to_s and
   !line.starts_with? __FILE__
  }
end

# Defer evaluation in case we're using spring loader (otherwise it would be something like "spring app    | app | started 13 secs ago | development")
# There's no way to set up deferred evaluation of PaperTrail.request.controller_info from here like
# we can with whodunnit, so abuse that property of PaperTrail.request.whodunnit to set other
# metadata. Reserve the whodunnit field for storing the actual name or id of the human who made the
# change.
PaperTrail.request.whodunnit = ->() {
  PaperTrail.set_global_metadata
  if Rails.const_defined?("Console") || $rails_rake_task
    "#{`whoami`.strip}: console"
  else
    "#{`whoami`.strip}: #{File.basename($PROGRAM_NAME)} #{ARGV.join ' '}"
  end
}

Rails.application.configure do
  console do
    PaperTrail.request.controller_info = { command: "rails console" }
    PaperTrail.request.whodunnit = ->() {
      PaperTrail.set_global_metadata

      @paper_trail_whodunnit ||= (
        if Rails.const_defined?("Console") || $rails_rake_task
          "#{`whoami`.strip}: console"
        else
          "#{`whoami`.strip}: #{File.basename($PROGRAM_NAME)} #{ARGV.join ' '}"
        end
      )
    }
  end
end
```

---

Note that in any place where record creation occurs outside of a request, you can manually set the `whodunnit` value to something specific if you don't want it blank.  E.g. in my seed file I do the following:

```rb
class SeedCreator
  def initialize
    PaperTrail.request.whodunnit = ->() {
      PaperTrail.set_global_metadata # save source_location & command
      "seed" # set whodunnit value to "seed"
    }
    create_campaign
    create_users
    # more seeding of models....
  end
end
```

In addition to improving the quality of your Papertrail table (knowing which command triggered a record update), this config should help you identify where phantom `whodunnits` are being saved.